# Corda - FlowMonitor - Flow with id X has been waiting for Y seconds to receive messages from parties

Tags: corda

In our Corda network we work with Accounts. We have a network with well-defined nodes.

To show the problem, imagine 3 nodes, PartyA, PartyB and Notary.
We created the accounts (AccountA for example) on PartyA. We have flows that can be executed at PartyB that has AccountA as a participant in the transaction.

Now imagine that PartyA is down for any reason, or communication between nodes is not available.
When I request a new AccountA key for PartyA, the flow gets stuck trying to communicate and does not return any exception. This happens in any situation that tries to communicate with another node, when running a CollectSignaturesFlow or ShareStateAndSyncAccounts to share account states for example.

The question is, is there any configuration or mechanism to return an exception in those cases where it is unable to communicate with another node?

Answer (score 0):

Timeouts can be handled differently depending on where you need to manage it.

There is the [flowTimeout](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/corda-configuration-fields.html#flowtimeout):

> When a flow implementing the TimedFlow interface and setting the
> isTimeoutEnabled flag does not complete within a defined elapsed time,
> it is restarted from the initial checkpoint.
>
> Currently only used for notarisation requests with clustered notaries

Or otherwise it can be done programmatically in your flow. I suggest you to take a look to this part of the Corda documentation ([Concurrency, Locking and Waiting](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/api-flows.html#concurrency-locking-and-waiting)) where there are many suggestions that you could try to implement.

Comment: Hey @marcos-pupo, what strategy did you choose eventually?